# Json with java hashmap

Tags: jquery, json, hashmap, gson

I have hashmap object,

```
Map testData=new HashMap();
testData.put("test","test1");
```

I am able to convert this map using json file with Gson library. I know how to get that data using jQuery getJSON.

My question is: how to display both key and value pairs?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a Map to JSON, so you can pass it to jQuery?

Comment: Could you please provide more detail? Do you have the http connection between server and client already in place?

Comment: No,I updated my question

Comment: Ah, I think I understand.  Are you asking how to print both the key and the value from each entry to an HTML page using jQuery?

Comment: @Chris:Yes,i know with using .each we can display.i dont have any item to iterate to display.

Comment: What do you mean by `i dont have any item to iterate to display`?  Do you mean the response from the server is empty?

Comment: My json have {"test":"test1"},i want to display  both the values

Comment: suppose take my json response getting as {"test","test1"}.Now i have to update input hidden element with name as test and value as test1.

Comment: Your JSON resonse should look like this: {"test": "test1"} not this: {"test","test1"}" (colon instead of comma). Could you verify this?

Answer (score 3):

What about using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) on the server side, and use jQuery's [.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) on the client-side?

EDIT: added a for-each example according to your changed question, try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5gEYf/

```
var response =  {"test": "test1"};
$.each(response, function(key, value) { 
    alert(key + ' -> ' + value); 
});
```

**EDIT:**

I stumbled upon this two year old answer of mine, and like to add that I would use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Home) for JSON de- / serialization in Java nowadays.

Comment: There's also Douglas Crockford's reference Java implementation. See http://www.json.org/java/ and https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java